# Prove that $f'(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}f(a+e^{i\theta})d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I know this is to be derived from Gauss' Mean Value Theorem, but I can't get the $e^{-i\theta}$. Where am I going wrong?

$f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{2pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(a+e^{i\theta}+h)-f(a+e^{i\theta})}{h}d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}ie^{i\theta}f'(a+e^{i\theta})d\theta$.

Clearly, this isn't correct, but I don't know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since $\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-i \theta} d\theta=0$, we can rewrite the integral as 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-i \theta}(f(a+e^{i \theta})-f(a)) d \theta= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{f(a+e^{i \theta})-f(a)}{a+e^{i \theta}-a} $$
Thus you are taking the mean value of the (analytic) function $$\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a} $$ over the unit circle.

I will also add that this function has a *removable* singularity at $z=a$, with limiting value $f'(a)$.

Comment: One quick question: Why can we rewrite the integral as such due to $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}d\theta = 0$?

Comment: @David open the brackets and use linearity of the integral. The second term will vanish.

Comment: Ah, so because $f(a)$ will just be a constant, and we know the integral for $e^{-i\theta} = 0$, so it will be $0$. ok.

Comment: @David precisely!

Comment: Would you say there is a straightforward generalization of this to the case $f^{(n)}(a)/(n!) = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-ni\theta}(f(a+e^{i\theta}))d\theta$?

Comment: I believe the first thing to note is that we get $f^n(a) = \int_0^{2\pi}n!e^{-ni\theta}\dots$.

Comment: @David There might be a generalization, but I can't see it. The trick of adding and subtracting $a$ to the denominator won't work as easily.